# Getting error while skipping the networkprofile check

Tags: powershell

I already made sure that I am running PS 2.0 on Windows 7 by running `$PSVersionTable` cmdlet.

When i run `Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck` I get following error:-

> Enable-PSRemoting: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'SkipNetworkProfileCheck'.

Answer (score 2):

Type `Get-Help Enable-PSRemoting`.

You will see that there is no such parameter in PS2.

The `SkipNetworkProfileCheck` parameter is included with Powershell 3.  You would need to install PS3.

Comment: I believe this is correct.  The Technet documentation is not clear that this was added in v3.